# How can I connect to existing databases from odoo application?

Tags: odoo-10, postgresql-9.3, odoo-9, odoo-11

I am using Odoo 10 version. I lost database connectivity from my application. While trying to select database using database selector (`ipaddress:portno/web/database/selector`) no databases are displaying.
Then I tried to create a new database.Then, only newly created database is showing. Then I entered directly to the backend and checked whether the databases are there or not. In backend(`postgresql`) databases are there. How can I connect to existing databases from odoo application?

Comment: Check owner of database might that is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Odoo shows the list database that belong to the user that you are using to connect to postgresql. So just change the owner of the database to be your user.